# T-SQL CTE to get parent

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I've tried working through some of the examples posted so far on the site but don't seem to be getting anywhere in applying them to my issue.

I have a table which contains list values, these values can have various parents associated with them, which are in the same table. Unfortunately it's a system provided table so I can't make any changes to how it works.

Here's a sample set of Data from my table EnumType

```
EnumTypeID     ParentEnumTypeID
1              Null
2              1
3              2
4              3
5              2
6              3
7              1
8              7
```

What I'm trying to do is find the ultimate parentenum of any child where 1 is the maximum hierarchy value (in the system, 1 is the root list, all values are descendants of 1). 
So for any provided ID I should be able to get the the top most parent specified that has their own parent of 1 (i.e. always return the second most layer where the enumtypeID has a parent = 1).
For example for the enumtypeid of 6 should return parentenumtypeid 2, enumtypeid 8 should return 7 etc.
I did have something previously but it only seems to be returning the next layer up and not the root value

```
WITH cte (enumtypeid, parentenumtypeid) AS
(
SELECT EnumTypeId,ParentEnumTypeId FROM EnumType WITH (NOLOCK)

UNION ALL
SELECT
e.enumtypeid, e.parentenumtypeid
FROM EnumType e
INNER JOIN cte ON cte.parentenumtypeid=e.EnumTypeId
WHERE e.ParentEnumTypeId IS NULL AND e.ParentEnumTypeId != '1'
)
```

To add some further context to this, here is my complete SQL. The query is part of a wider query to retrieve some change request details from my helpdesk database

```
declare @planguagecode nvarchar(3) = 'ENU'
declare @putcoffset int = 1

WITH ChangeEnum (enumtypeid, parentenumtypeid) AS
(
SELECT EnumTypeId,ParentEnumTypeId FROM EnumType WITH (NOLOCK)

UNION ALL
SELECT
e.enumtypeid, e.parentenumtypeid
FROM EnumType e
INNER JOIN ChangeEnum ON ChangeEnum.parentenumtypeid=e.EnumTypeId
WHERE e.ParentEnumTypeId IS NULL AND e.ParentEnumTypeId != '28F88C04-D11D-78C0-A237-FA9ABD6C6478'
)
SELECT DISTINCT
crq.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C as 'id', 
crq.Title_9691DD10_7211_C835_E3E7_6B38AF8B8104 as 'title', 
COALESCE(sds.DisplayName, 'No Status') as 'status', 
COALESCE(cds.DisplayName, 'Uncategorised') as 'category', 
COALESCE(ads.DisplayName, 'Not Assigned') as 'area', 
COALESCE(rds.DisplayName,'Not Assessed') as 'risk', 
COALESCE(pds.DisplayName,'Not Assigned') as 'priority', 
COALESCE(CASE WHEN rads.DisplayName != ads.DisplayName THEN RADS.DisplayName ELSE ADS.Displayname END,'Not Assigned') as 'rootarea',
CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),DATEADD(mi, @pUTCOffset, crq.CreatedDate_6258638D_B885_AB3C_E316_D00782B8F688),120) as 'created',
CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),DATEADD(mi, @pUTCOffset, crq.ScheduledStartDate_89429D01_365C_366D_FCDA_3198102B180C),120) as 'start', 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),DATEADD(mi, @pUTCOffset, crq.ScheduledEndDate_6FC72C26_565D_CB2A_BBAF_6A699C15FE99),120) as 'end'
FROM MTV_System$WorkItem$ChangeRequest crq WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN DisplayStringView rds WITH (NOLOCK) ON crq.Risk_B9DCB168_B698_6864_E562_08F986C1D4E0 = rds.LTStringId AND rds.LanguageCode = @pLanguageCode
LEFT JOIN DisplayStringView ads WITH (NOLOCK) ON crq.Area_BC1C6C5B_F242_D568_BE10_FC23CD14655A = ads.LTStringId AND ads.LanguageCode = @pLanguageCode
LEFT JOIN DisplayStringView sds WITH (NOLOCK) ON crq.Status_72C1BC70_443C_C96F_A624_A94F1C857138 = sds.LTStringID AND sds.LanguageCode = @pLanguageCode
LEFT JOIN DisplayStringView cds WITH (NOLOCK) ON crq.Category_7B1892FE_108A_EC85_064D_7815C2DFC442 = cds.LTStringID AND cds.LanguageCode = @pLanguageCode
LEFT JOIN DisplayStringView pds WITH (NOLOCK) ON crq.Priority_B1226A17_0705_8F13_1ED4_74A38D2E1707 = pds.LTStringId AND pds.LanguageCode = @pLanguageCode
LEFT JOIN ChangeEnum ce on crq.Area_BC1C6C5B_F242_D568_BE10_FC23CD14655A=ce.enumtypeid
LEFT JOIN DisplayStringView rads WITH (NOLOCK) ON ce.parentenumtypeid = RADS.LTStringId AND RADS.LanguageCode = @pLanguageCode AND RADS.LTStringId ! ='28F88C04-D11D-78C0-A237-FA9ABD6C6478'
WHERE 
    crq.ScheduledStartDate_89429D01_365C_366D_FCDA_3198102B180C IS NOT NULL /* Scheduled */ AND 
    crq.Status_72C1BC70_443C_C96F_A624_A94F1C857138 = '6d6c64dd-07ac-aaf5-f812-6a7cceb5154d' /* In Progress */
```

So to summarise, I need to get the top most parent ID of the child which has a parent id of 1. In this instance the parent 1 which has not parent itself, is just a place holder for the table. The child id's are supplied by the query above from another table.

Comment: giving that table, you should always get 1? Is that right?

Comment: no, I need the value beneath 1. the parent of every child should have the parent ID of 1. Sorry I didn't make it clear, couldn't quite explain it

Comment: if Id provided is 6, what's the expected value? 2?

Comment: 2 would be the expected value in that instance

Comment: Aside: `e.ParentEnumTypeId != '1'` looks like comparing an integer to a string. (Since your DDL is secret we can't know.) Generally not a helpful practice.

Comment: I have simplified the ID's as they're typically 32 character guids

Answer (score 0):

This works for the provided table example. I use 6 for demostration

```
declare @leaf int = 6

while exists (select * from enums where parentenumtypeid <> 1 and enumtypeid = @leaf)
    select @leaf = parentenumtypeid from enums where enumtypeid = @leaf;
    print @leaf;
```

EDIT

```
    CREATE FUNCTION FindCustomParent (@input VARCHAR(250))
RETURNS VARCHAR(250)
AS BEGIN
    declare @output int
    set @output = @input

while exists (select * from ChangeEnum where parentenumtypeid <> '28F88C04-D11D-78C0-A237-FA9ABD6C6478' and enumtypeid = @output)
    select @output = parentenumtypeid from ChangeEnum where enumtypeid = @output;
    return @output
END


    SELECT DISTINCT
    crq.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C as 'id', 
    crq.Title_9691DD10_7211_C835_E3E7_6B38AF8B8104 as 'title', 
    COALESCE(sds.DisplayName, 'No Status') as 'status', 
    COALESCE(cds.DisplayName, 'Uncategorised') as 'category', 
    COALESCE(ads.DisplayName, 'Not Assigned') as 'area', 
    COALESCE(rds.DisplayName,'Not Assessed') as 'risk', 
    COALESCE(pds.DisplayName,'Not Assigned') as 'priority', 
    COALESCE(CASE WHEN rads.DisplayName != ads.DisplayName THEN RADS.DisplayName ELSE ADS.Displayname END,'Not Assigned') as 'rootarea',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),DATEADD(mi, @pUTCOffset, crq.CreatedDate_6258638D_B885_AB3C_E316_D00782B8F688),120) as 'created',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),DATEADD(mi, @pUTCOffset, crq.ScheduledStartDate_89429D01_365C_366D_FCDA_3198102B180C),120) as 'start', 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),DATEADD(mi, @pUTCOffset, crq.ScheduledEndDate_6FC72C26_565D_CB2A_BBAF_6A699C15FE99),120) as 'end',

    dbo.FindFirstParent(crq.Area_BC1C6C5B_F242_D568_BE10_FC23CD14655A) as Parent

    FROM MTV_System$WorkItem$ChangeRequest crq WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN DisplayStringView rds WITH (NOLOCK) ON crq.Risk_B9DCB168_B698_6864_E562_08F986C1D4E0 = rds.LTStringId AND rds.LanguageCode = @pLanguageCode
    LEFT JOIN DisplayStringView ads WITH (NOLOCK) ON crq.Area_BC1C6C5B_F242_D568_BE10_FC23CD14655A = ads.LTStringId AND ads.LanguageCode = @pLanguageCode
    LEFT JOIN DisplayStringView sds WITH (NOLOCK) ON crq.Status_72C1BC70_443C_C96F_A624_A94F1C857138 = sds.LTStringID AND sds.LanguageCode = @pLanguageCode
    LEFT JOIN DisplayStringView cds WITH (NOLOCK) ON crq.Category_7B1892FE_108A_EC85_064D_7815C2DFC442 = cds.LTStringID AND cds.LanguageCode = @pLanguageCode
    LEFT JOIN DisplayStringView pds WITH (NOLOCK) ON crq.Priority_B1226A17_0705_8F13_1ED4_74A38D2E1707 = pds.LTStringId AND pds.LanguageCode = @pLanguageCode
    LEFT JOIN ChangeEnum ce on crq.Area_BC1C6C5B_F242_D568_BE10_FC23CD14655A=ce.enumtypeid
    LEFT JOIN DisplayStringView rads WITH (NOLOCK) ON ce.parentenumtypeid = RADS.LTStringId AND RADS.LanguageCode = @pLanguageCode AND RADS.LTStringId ! ='28F88C04-D11D-78C0-A237-FA9ABD6C6478'
    WHERE 
        crq.ScheduledStartDate_89429D01_365C_366D_FCDA_3198102B180C IS NOT NULL /* Scheduled */ AND 
        crq.Status_72C1BC70_443C_C96F_A624_A94F1C857138 = '6d6c64dd-07ac-aaf5-f812-6a7cceb5154d' /* In Progress */
```

Comment: Tree structure: https://yellowpencil.com/blog/how-to-represent-a-tree-structure-numerically-in-sql-server/

Comment: just to make it more complicated, the child node is supplied from the query I included above. SInce I don't know the child ID at the time I don't think I can declare it

Comment: You can create a `sql function` and call it in your `query`

Comment: I've no idea how to do that, my SQL is quite limited and I'd found an article when mentioned a CTE would be the right way to go in order to find the specified parent from any child. It's also not my database so I can't change anything.

Comment: Still not right I'm afraid, the value which gets looked up is LEFT JOIN ChangeEnum ce on crq.Area_BC1C6C5B_F242_D568_BE10_FC23CD14655A=ce.enumtypeid which feeds into the cte above if that makes sense, with the idea being that I know the child area value from the query so show me the root from the cte at the start

Comment: Did not understand. On the other hand, i removed the temporary table

Answer (score 0):

The following demonstrates using a common table expression (CTE) to walk the tree while keeping track of the first level of children below the root.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Enums as Table ( EnumTypeId Int Identity, ParentEnumTypeId Int );
insert into @Enums ( ParentEnumTypeId ) values
  ( NULL ), ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 ), ( 1 ), ( 7 );
select * from @Enums;

-- Walk the tree tracking the parentage.
with
  Enums as (
    -- Start at the roots which have a   NULL   parent.
    select EnumTypeId, ParentEnumTypeId, Cast( NULL as Int ) as PenultimateParentEnumTypeId, 0 as Depth
      from @Enums
      where ParentEnumTypeId is NULL
    union all
    -- Add each level of leaves.
    select CE.EnumTypeId, CE.ParentEnumTypeId,
      -- If the parent has no parent or, equivalently, the parent's depth is zero, then capture the
      --   child's   EnumTypeId .
      case when E.ParentEnumTypeId is NULL then CE.EnumTypeId else PenultimateParentEnumTypeId end,
      -- case when E.Depth = 0 then CE.EnumTypeId else PenultimateParentEnumTypeId end,
      E.Depth + 1
      from Enums as E inner join
        @Enums as CE on CE.ParentEnumTypeId = E.EnumTypeId )
  -- Output the results.
  select EnumTypeId, ParentEnumTypeId, PenultimateParentEnumTypeId, Depth
    from Enums
    order by EnumTypeId;
```

Comment: This looks to be on the right lines, though I seem to be struggling to implement in conjunction with my query above. Likely simplifying the actual id's for integers is what's tripping me up here as they are stored as 32 character guids. I am also interested in only getting to a point where the parent ID has a specific value so I'm assuming instead of where parentenumtypeid = null I can substitute the value I'm interested in as the max value

Comment: You can switch to the `case when E.Depth = 0 ...` expression if that makes it easier for you. The results are the same. Replace the `Int` in `Cast( NULL as Int )` with the appropriate datatype, e.g. `VarChar(32)`. The last part of your comment is a bit unclear, but I think you want to add `where PenultimateParentEnumTypeId = 'Your Specific GUID String'` to the last `select`.